# MySQL: How to specify a common condition over multiple columns in a table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 24 columns (`jan1, jan2, feb1, feb2, mar1, mar2,....dec1,dec2`), with unique ids (1 to N) as rows. Cell values will be either 1 (true) or 2 (false). Now I want to query for a particular row where all months (columns) have `1` (true) value.

I can write query like

```
select * form [table] 
where id=232 and 
      jan1=1 and jan2=1 and feb1=1 ....... and dec2=1;
```

But looking for a better solution, if any. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**:

Concatenate all the column values of a row and compare with `111111111111111111111111` for equality.

```
select * from [table] 
where id = 232 and 
      concat( jan1, jan2, feb1, ......., dec2 ) = '111111111111111111111111`;
```

**Solution 2**:

Concatenate all the column values of a row and replace all `1'`s with empty character and compare the length for `0`.

```
select * from [table] 
where id = 232 and 
      length( replace( concat( jan1, jan2, feb1, ......., dec2 ),
                       '1', 
                       '' )
            ) = 0;
```

Comment: Can you please help what to do if I need to retrieve those months having 1 (true) value for a particular row (say id=232)?

Comment: Yes, thanks; Your solution checks for value=1 for all columns of row with id=232 and retrieves if true. But what if only some cells have 1 and others have 2 (false) and I need to retrieve only those months (columns) having 1 value? Please help. Sorry if I haven't conveyed properly earlier.